# the Barcode Scanner from googles mlkit doesn't recognize any barcodes

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

So i followed googles tutorial for their barcode scanner ([this one](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android#java)) and the qr scanning works like a charm. The only problem is that i don't need qr codes but rather bar codes. But they don't work. It doesn't detect anything. I tried multiple online bar codes and ones from around the house but none got recognised as a barcode.

this is the code in my activity that handles the image and scanner:

```
public void btnClick(View v) {

    Intent imageTakeIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if(imageTakeIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
        startActivityForResult(imageTakeIntent, 101);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==101 && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        image = InputImage.fromBitmap(imageBitmap, 0);
        barCodeScanning();
    }
}

public void barCodeScanning(){
    BarcodeScannerOptions options =
            new BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
                    .setBarcodeFormats(
                            Barcode.FORMAT_CODE_128,
                            Barcode.FORMAT_CODE_93,
                            Barcode.FORMAT_CODE_93,
                            Barcode.FORMAT_CODABAR,
                            Barcode.FORMAT_EAN_13,
                            Barcode.FORMAT_EAN_8,
                            Barcode.FORMAT_ITF,
                            Barcode.FORMAT_UPC_A,
                            Barcode.FORMAT_UPC_E,
                            Barcode.FORMAT_PDF417,
                            Barcode.FORMAT_DATA_MATRIX,
                            Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE,
                            Barcode.FORMAT_AZTEC)
                    .build();
    BarcodeScanner scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient();
    Task<List<Barcode>> result = scanner.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Barcode>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<Barcode> barcodes) {
                    System.out.println(barcodes.size());
                    for (Barcode barcode: barcodes) {
                        Rect bounds = barcode.getBoundingBox();
                        Point[] corners = barcode.getCornerPoints();

                        String rawValue = barcode.getRawValue();
                        System.out.println(rawValue);

                        int valueType = barcode.getValueType();
                        System.out.println(valueType);
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
}
```

The console looks fine to me except the line  `E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.hardware.chipname"` which is marked red but didn't turn up any helpful results on google.
This is the complete console output:

```
02/26 18:29:10: Launching 'app' on HMD Global Nokia 5.3.
Install successfully finished in 2 s 230 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.project.kuecheninventar/com.project.kuecheninventar.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 28314 on device 'hmd_global-nokia_5_3-N0AA003687KA2700363'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
W/kuecheninventa: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/AdrenoGLES: QUALCOMM build                   : cfd6c90, Id60e6598a1
Build Date                       : 01/27/20
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.27.05.03
Local Branch                     : mybranchea40f85b-21cb-f1fb-b0c0-5cb90179c3e0
Remote Branch                    : quic/gfx-adreno.lnx.1.0.r91-rel
Remote Branch                    : NONE
Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
Build Config                     : S P 8.0.12 AArch64
I/AdrenoGLES: PFP: 0x016ee187, ME: 0x00000000
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Scheduling upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) with jobId=-1883559869 in 86400000ms(Backend next call timestamp 0). Attempt 1
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.mlkit.dynamite.barcode:10000 and remote module com.google.mlkit.dynamite.barcode:0
Selected local version of com.google.mlkit.dynamite.barcode
I/tflite: Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
I/native: barcode_detector_client.cc:239 Not using NNAPI
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.hardware.chipname"
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
I/System.out: 0
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
```

The line `System.out.println(barcodes.size());` just prints 0 which means the barcode list is empty. Did i do something wrong or why does the qr code regognize but no bar code?

Comment: Mysterious :) In order to help you better, could you provide:
1. which version / variant (bundled/unbundled) of the Barcode scanning API are you using
2. examples of one or two of the 1D barcodes

"E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.hardware.chipname" is a red herring, not related to this issue. It's basically a check for HW accelerator that is failing.

You could also see if you can reproduce with our official quickstart app: https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart

Comment: @Chrisito im using the bundled version. Here are 2 barcodes i tested: https://imgur.com/a/eN9hvuj
could you tell me how to compile the github version? I get the error 'Error: The apk for your currently selected variant (Unknown output) is not signed. Please specify a signing configuration for this variant (proguard).' in the Run/Debug Configuration window in AndroidStudio.

Comment: Thanks. Let me get some help from more knowledgable folks, please stay tuned.

Comment: Hi, those barcodes can be detected using the mlkit quickstart app. If you want to recognize barcode from a local image, could you check the mlkit quickstart app code here: https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/369dd896f4b7fadeedd3e0860f2e1695db0b4d9b/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/StillImageActivity.java#L297 for reading a bitmap from url and feed it to the barcode scanner api? There might be an issue with the InputImage.

Comment: BTW, to build the mlkit vision quickstart app you can change the build variant if you use Android Studio: select Build > Select Build Variant in the menu bar.

Check more details in the answers here: https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/issues/123

Comment: @mr.jogurt any update, I hope you got 1D bar code scanning working in the end?

Comment: @Chrisito thanks for both your help. I added another solution (via zxing) as an answer. I used this solution because the deadline on the university project was coming up.

Answer (score -2):

I forgot about this issue because i solved through another way. So here is my solution with zxing:
In the app built.gradle use `implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.1.0'`

```
public class BarCodeScanner extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        scan();
    }

    private void scan() {
        IntentIntegrator i = new IntentIntegrator(this);

        i.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);

        i.setCaptureActivity(CaptureActivitaet.class);
        i.setOrientationLocked(false);
        i.setBeepEnabled(false);
        i.setPrompt("Scanning");
        i.initiateScan();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        IntentResult res = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (res != null) {
            if (res.getContents() != null) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(res.getContents());
                builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.scanComplete));
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra("code", res.getContents()));
                    finish();
                }).setNegativeButton(R.string.scanAgain, (dialogInterface, i) -> scan());
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Results", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

The capture activity is just an empty activity `public class CaptureActivitaet extends CaptureActivity {}` although it has to be configured in the Manifest file like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.project.Grocerly.UI.CaptureActivitaet"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

This opens a fullscreen camera activity which scans codes accordingly to the types set via `i.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);` in the `scan()` methode. The extra capture activity can probably be skipped if you use `setCaptureActivity(this.class)` and configure it correctly in the manifest file but im not sure about that.

Because this was a project for university this code isn't very pretty but it works and that was my main concern at the time.

Comment: ZXing is in maintenance mode only and shouldn't be used anymore. I have the same issue as in the question -this is not the answer but a workaround.